# How to get sessions which were added after socket.io is conneted in socket.request

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, express-session

I want to get `user` property in session after login, but when i set session after login, `socket.request.session` doesn't change, there is no `user` property in it. But i can get it in router.post.

I tried to edit sessions in `router.post()/router.get()`, `socket.request.session` was still not change.

#### index.js

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen('8082', { origins: '*' })
const schedule = require('node-schedule')

io.set('transports', [
  'websocket',
  'flashsocket',
  'htmlfile',
  'xhr-polling',
  'jsonp-polling',
  'polling'
])
io.set('origins', '*:*')

const app = new express()

const sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore({ reapInterval: 3600 * 1000 })
const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'Stefanie Sun',
    store: sessionStore,
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        maxAge: 8 * 3600 * 1000,
        secure: false
  }, 
    rolling: true
})
io.use((socket, next) => {
  sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
})
app.use(sessionMiddleware)
routes(app)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const comment_schedule = schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * * * * *', async () => {         /** 10s查询一次是否有新的内容 **/
    const COOKIE_STR = socket.request.session
    console.log(COOKIE_STR)
  })
})
```

#### router.js

```
...
router.post('/pagelist', (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.user = { username: 'test1', gender: 'x', bio: 'this is a test' }
  console.log(req.session)
  res.status(200).json({ code: 'OK' })
}
app.user('/api/page', router)
```

when i visited `/api/page/pagelist` after signin, i wish i can get the same session in `socket.request` and `req.session` in router.post,
but `socket.request.session` is

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-04-07T22:57:13.379Z,
     originalMaxAge: 28800000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false } }
```

but in router.post `req.session` is

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-04-07T22:57:48.146Z,
     originalMaxAge: 28799999,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false },
  user:
   { 
     username: 'test1',
     gender: 'x',
     bio: 'this is a test'
}}
```

i hope in `socket.request.session` i can also get
`user` property.

My fontend project is with Vue.js. And i set `socket.on('event')` in home.vue. I connect socket.io before the page logins, and after login i set user property in session, i can't get this property in `socket.request.session`.

#### login code in frontend

```
// api.js
export const loginApi = ({ username, password } = { username: '', password: '' }) => {
    const data = {
        username,
        password
    };
    return axios.request({
        url: '/api/signin',
        data: qs.stringify(data),
        method: 'post'
    })
}

// login.vue
submit() {
    loginApi({ username: this.username, password: this.password})
       .then((result: any) => {
            this.$toast.success('login success');
            this.Cookies.set('user', this.username, { expires: 7 });
            getUserInfo(this.username).then((res: any) => {
                const { data } = res;
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));
                const url = this.redirect && this.redirect || '/pages';
                this.$router.push(url);
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: How does your page login?  Is it logging in via Ajax rather than via a form post?  If you login via a form post, then the session cookie and server-side session object is established before the next page after the form post will connect on socket.io so this problem would not normally occur.  So, I guess we want to know why socket.io connects before you are logged in as that's what causes this?

Comment: I connected socket.io before login, and added user session after login.  Should i connect socket.io after login?

Comment: Would you please answer the question I asked above.  How are you logging in?  Ajax?  Form post?   Please show that code.  If a login cookie is established BEFORE you connect socket.io, then you can use that to get to the session.

Comment: FYI, you may need to add some socket.io middleware to get `socket.handshake.session` filled in appropriately if the login is established BEFORE your socket.io connection happens.  Example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session).

Comment: I use axios to login. I add the code in the main question